# Find $s$ so the integral converges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have the following integral:

$$ \int_0^1  \left( \frac{x}{(x-1)^2} \right) ^s dx$$

I need to find the values of $s$ for which the integral converges. 
I’ve tried using the comparison test but I only get $s<1$ (which is true) but does not help me to get to the answer which is $-1<s<\frac12$.

Does anybody have an idea of what else can i do?

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5Es%2F%28x-1%29%5E%282s%29+from+0+to+1) shows an equivalent form using the gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The function is integrable iff $x^{s}$ is integrable near $0$ and $(x-1)^{-2s}$ is integrable near $1$. So the conditions are $s >-1$ and $s <\frac 1 2$.

Comment: How do you get to those conditions? I didn’t get that part.

Comment: You can see when $\int_{\frac 1 2} ^{1} (x-1)^{-2s}dx$ converges by explicitly computing the integral. Similarly you can see when $\int_0^{\frac 1 2} x^{s}dx$ converges.